# Elemento fixado a cima do teclado

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Criei um `RelativeLayout` com propriedade `match_parent` na altura para que possa preencher a tela inteira. Dentro dele inseri um `LinearLayout` com propriedade `alignParentBottom` tendo valor `true` para fixar o elemento no rodapé.

Quando clico e estabeleço foco no `EditText`, meu teclado sobrepõe o elemento. Eu gostaria que esse `LinearLayout` permanecesse fixado a cima do teclado do dispositivo.

Para ser mais claro peguei essa imagem do aplicativo do Twitter:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Código:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="O que esta acontecendo?"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#666"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logo abaixo tem um GIF mostrando o código a cima funcionando. Quando é dado o foco no `EditText`, a parte cinza é sobreposta pelo teclado. Já tentei usar `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` em minha `Activity`, porém não deu certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para que meu elemento permaneça fixado a cima do teclado sem ser sobreposto?

Answer (score 1):

Você já tentou adicionar o adjustPan no seu manifest?

Exemplo:

```
<activity
   android:name=".SuaActivity"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize">
</activity>
```

Isso vai fazer que quando o teclado for aberto, ele empurre todo o layout para ficar em cima do teclado.

Comment: Já sim Leonardo, não funciona desta forma.